# Aligning buttons in Android

Tags: android

Looking for advice on how to better align these buttons.  Probably many ways to do this.  Perhaps center all three buttons vertically since they are different size buttons?  Right now the buttons just look haphazard, because I am brand new to Android programming.

Here is the current button code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.redacted.redacted.HomeScreen$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="#ff6d8416">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Beginner / Principiante"
    android:id="@+id/beginnerButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/intermediateButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Intermediate / Intermedio"
    android:id="@+id/intermediateButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/beginnerButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/beginnerButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Advanced / Advanzado"
    android:id="@+id/advancedButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/intermediateButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/intermediateButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/intermediateButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="redacted"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my current result

[image]

Comment: You can post a link to images on somewhere like imgur.com then users with enough rep can add the images for you. Images of what you are getting and what you want are very helpful with these types of questions. Right now, it's a little unclear what you would like to happen

Comment: No problem,  here is what the buttons look like so far: http://imgur.com/kUpCp8M

Comment: please post a screen capture

Comment: Can you also post the complete xml? You are missing at least the root element

Comment: OK I added the entire XML, but StackOverFlow doesn't show the first part that starts with "Relative Layout" for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Beginner"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Intermediate"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Advanced"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

A vertically oriented `LinearLayout` with a few changes should work perfectly for you. Here's an example

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Beginner / Principiante"
        android:id="@+id/beginnerButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Intermediate / Intermedio"
        android:id="@+id/intermediateButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Advanced / Advanzado"
        android:id="@+id/advancedButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

note the changes I have made. Especially with the `gravity` and removing what is probably `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` that won't be needed. If this doesn't work (I haven't had a chance to test just yet) wrapping the `Button`s in another `LinearLayout` and giving that a `gravity="center"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vertical LinearLayout and set margins to create the gaps around them.

Comment: I did a linear layout and used people's suggestions on removing the code related to relative layout.  I would post my exact xml code but Stack Overflow is limiting my comment size.  Thanks everyone!